# Angular 9 - NGCC fails with an unhandled exception

Tags: angular, typescript, ivy, angular-compiler

Building the application after having upgraded dependencies to Angular 9 (and having performed the necessary code changes) throws an error:

> Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015   Compiling
> @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015   Compiling @angular/core :
> es2015 as esm2015   Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
> Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
> **Error**: Error on worker #5: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null

It then goes on to throw the below error:

> Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015   Compiling
> @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015   Compiling
> @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
> **Error**: Tried to write node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts.__ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back
> up file   but it already exists so not writing, nor backing up,
> node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts.

This error may be because two or more entry-points overlap and ngcc has been asked to process some files more than once.
You should check other entry-points in this package and set up a configuration to ignore any that you are not using.

> Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015   An unhandled exception
> occurred: NGCC failed.

Answer (score 101):

This problem (NGCC failed) was encountered by me and my colleague developer on our localhost machines.

It would be important to remark that the development and production machines were running well.

In order to solve this problem, we've followed the following steps:

1. in file *tsconfig.json*, in **angularCompilerOptions** have set ("**enableIvy**": false)
2. updated Node.js to the latest version (executing **node -v** returned v14.3.0)
3. have deleted the [node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder folder: (executing `rm .\node_modules\` (on Windows), make sure it has been deleted successfully)
4. have installed the packages (executing `npm i`)
5. here the project is ready to be built. It builds and runs without errors now.

Comment: Re-installing node_modules did it for me

Comment: setting the `"enableIvy":false` did the trick for me

Comment: I had the problem after adding a new npm module to ng9 app. deleting node_modules worked!

Comment: How could setting `enableIvy` to false be a solution when it would result in a much bigger bundle after the project is built?

Comment: "enableIvy":false did the trick 

Previously i didnt had this error, until used a custom webpack builder.

Comment: Downgrade @angular-devkit/build-angular works for me.
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.6"

Comment: I was able to get this fixed without having to setting ivy to false.

Answer (score 52):

In my particular case, the **@angular-devkit/build-angular** was updated to "**^0.1001.2**" in my *package.json* file after running the *npm audit fix*. (This version seems to belong to Angular 10, instead of the local projects' Angular version (v9.1.7))

After reverting this change, everything started working again:

"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "**~0.901.6**"

Comment: I had exactly the same issue.

Comment: Great soultion. No need to use "enableIvy": false

Comment: I also had the exact same problem. This solved it. Thanks

Comment: I set "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.6" and install npm again. now working correctly. thanks

Comment: Downgrade @angular-devkit/build-angular works for me. "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.6"

Answer (score 26):

Using terminal/[cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe),

First step:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Second step:

```
ng update
```

Third step:

```
ng serve
```

It fixed mine.

***Note***

Your custom CSS files in the [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) folder might get deleted. Back them up before and place them back after the update!

---

**Global Solution**

With solution above you need to do the "First step" on each project. In case you wanted to upgrade your Angular CLI/Core versions globally for all feature projects, upgrade your Angular version with this command:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Then run the Second and Third steps above.

Comment: Worked for me. Saved my time, Thanks

Comment: why would the right answer be to change ng versions? That decision should not be made lightly.

Comment: Well, weirdly enough, upgrading angular to the latest stable release fixed the extension giving that error. Thanks. In my case, upgrading the major angular release from 11 to 12 wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 21):

This issue is because you might be running your application on any port and Angular ngcc was assigned with a particular process id which was specified and locked in a file called
`__ngcc_lock_file__` inside `\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc`.

If you are doing a hard system turn off or if your OS crashed, this lock file will be there in the [node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder. And once you turn on you machine and are trying to start the application again, Angular CLI will check this lock file and try to find the process id specified in the file. Most of the time that process id will be missing since you did a complete machine restart and it will throw this error.

**Solution 1**. Remove folder *node_modules* and do *npm install*

**Solution 2**. Smart solution - delete the lock file as below.

Go to `\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc`, find the file named `__ngcc_lock_file__`, and delete it.
Done.

Answer (score 17):

Try to remove the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder and run install again:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

```
npm install
```

For me it has solved the problem.

Comment: You do not have to remove the whole `node_modules`, `node_modules/@angular` folder is enough. But, anyway, do not forget to `npm i`.

Answer (score 10):

Adding `"postinstall": "ngcc"` to `"scripts"` in package.json helped me to fix this

Comment: Works for me, best solution IMO.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, adding `enableIvy: false` didn't solve the issue, which was with the Angular Language Service Extension for [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) (it looks like it's not actually taking the parameter into account).

The solution has been to downgrade the extension version. (v12.0.0 --> v11.2.14. [See here to know how](https://gparlakov.medium.com/downgrade-vs-code-extension-d8c2b0440fbe)).

Comment: I am currently stuck with Node JS 12 and this is the only solution that worked for me. Also, it has the advantage of not disabling Ivy. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Setting *"enableIvy": false* in file *tsconfig.json* does fix that particular error. Ivy is supposed to be usable already.

I found this in [clement911's answer to *Error after updated to version 9 #36060*](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36060), and it worked for me after a lot of testing.

Answer (score 4):

I had to go into my tsconfig.spec.json file and add

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
}
```

It was already in my tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 3):

Check your Node.js version with `node -v`. And check if Angular 9 is compatible with it.

Updating Node.js to the latest LTS version (12.8.1) worked for me.
I did this with nvm (Node Version Manager).
I found good instructions [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version).

Answer (score 3):

- I removed *tslib.js* from file *package.json*
- Removed file *package-lock.json*
- Deleted the [node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder
- `npm i`
- `ng serve`

It worked for me.

Comment: thanks @abhi. Worked for me but created package-lock.json file again.

Comment: That's what happens when you run npm i

Comment: @Ben Taliadoros: Point being?

Comment: That when you run that command the package-lock.json is created and it's intentional. It didn't seem that Anant was expecting that

Answer (score 3):

Well, in my case I was trying to run an Angular project of an older version with a newer version of [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js). I did this:

Removed all the existing nodule modules.

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Updated Node.js to the latest:

```
npm update
npm install
```

Updated the Angular project version to the latest

```
ng update @angular/core
```

Updated the project cli to the latest

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

Now start the project

```
ng-serve
```

Comment: I would be VERY HESITENT to delete `node_modules`, at least rename it to a bkup until you figure out that you solved everything. `mv node_modules ~/node_modules.bkup`

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove *angular-font-awesome* and run install again:

```
npm uninstall angular-font-awesome
ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.6.0
```

The problem is solved after I removed fontawesome and now Material Icons is my choice for icons.

But I should say thank you for Font Awesome for many years of free awesome icons
:)

Answer (score 1):

in that case version mismatch..
check first version node JS and angular JS

then write : **npm install** =>
: ng serve

if have port issue : **ng server --port 4201**

Answer (score 1):

I got this and other bugs because I tried to update some marginal libraries of an Angular 9 application. The errors that subsequently appeared during compilation were senseless in the sense that they did not help to correct the error.

The solution by deleting "node_modules" and "npm i" does not work, because even though I have the original *package.json* file, "npm i" still installs different versions of the libraries—not the original ones. What exactly were the libraries in folder [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder originally is not known.

**The only solution** that helped was to **restore the node_modules folder from backup**.

Otherwise, if you need to update the libraries in the application, [take a vacation and prepare some antidepressants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYBm5NPTuHQ&t=03m21s), but it still may not help in a matter of days to solve meaningless errors after upgrading the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a situation where disabling [Ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ivy) is the best solution.

For Windows users:

```js
npm i rimraf -g
rimraf node_modules
npm i
```

Answer (score 1):

For older Angular versions, I managed to fix this through Visual Studio extensions.

Angular CLI: 6.1.5 
Node: 8.11.4

[Visual Studio, Angular extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcCNq.png)

[Angular view engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMZmc.png)

*Extensions* → *Angular Language Service(v12.0.2)* → *Extension Settings*

- Under *Workspace*, put a check on "User Legacy View Engine language service".

Comment: Re *"Visual Studio"*: Don't you mean *"[Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)"*? They are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue and none of the above answers helped.

My solution:

- navigate to root ng project folder
- run cmd command: `./node_modules/.bin/ngc tsconfig.json`
- this exposed a real error: one of the component `*.spec.ts` files (test files) had an error (I removed a dependency earlier). This wasn't surfaced by default when building or trying VS Code debugging.
- After fixing the error, both VS Code debugger and `./node_modules/.bin/ngc tsconfig.json` command succeeded

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

In my case, updating Node.js to a new version helped.

Answer (score 0):

I generally advise people to make a manual backup of the project after every succeeded deployment (locally) because, when you face this kind of problem (everything related to `NGCC errors`) you can just hard delete the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder and restore it from your *last backup*. And then build again.

Sometimes, when you cannot afford updating Node.js to the **last version**, this solution would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed the *angular-font-awesome package* from npm and then [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29). It might got conflicted, but I just removed the previously installed angular-font-awesome and then did a `ng build`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I ran `ionic build` while the project built just fine with my colleagues. So we ran `ng -v` to compare our packages. It turns out I had higher versions of `@angular-devkit/build-angular`, `@angular-devkit/build-optimizer` and `@angular-devkit/build-webpack` . Each of them was version 0.1001.2, and our project was running with 0.901.8.

So I ran `npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular 0.1001.2` to uninstall it, and `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular 0.901.8` to downgrade. On running `ng -v` again, the other two had downgraded as well.

Finally, `ionic build` was a success! We lived happily thereafter, till we run into different problems. [Working packages for our project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPIsE.png)

Answer (score 0):

"prettier": "2.2.1". Remove this, as it is interferes with semantics.

Comment: That is a bit terse. Can you elaborate, please? E.g., remove from what? What do you mean by *"interferes with semantics"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67328394/edit), not here in comments (********************** ***without*** ************ "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out we had used the package-lock.json stated package versioning for a while, and when I tried to delete it due to merge conflicts and recreated it, the error happened. When going back to the old package-lock.json, the problem was gone. So I started searching:

- comparing changes between both
- checking if problem appears in production, too - then it almost can't be a dev dependency
- sorting out improbable and probable dependencies

I ended up at the Angular dependencies, more exactly at the @angular/material-moment-adapter having received an update (as we allow it in the package.json)
from version 11.2.0 to 11.2.12.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that my server did not have enough RAM (1 GB), which seems not be enough to process a build. After increasing it to 2 GB, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Visual Studio Code 1.62 or later. None of those answers helped me.

I updated Visual Studio Code yesterday (2021-10-11) and for some reason my Angular 9 project started to show "NGCC failed". I downgraded Visual Studio Code to 1.61.2 and everything came back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the previous answers worked.

Downgrading **typescript** (4.8 to 4.6 in my case) resolved the issue.

Comment: *How* did you downgrade? Please respond by editing your answer (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -2):

This only woked for me
del node_modules
npm install
enableIvy:false was not support who uses angular v12 or above

Answer (score -6):

Replace file *tsconfig.json* by the below JSON content:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,

  "compilerOptions": {
     "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: surely "target": "es2015" is enable proper compilation

Comment: Hi! The reason this answer is getting downvoted by your peers, is it simply isn't helpful enough.  What are the parts that help to address the unhandled exception that the OP is asking about?  Explaining the reasoning behind your answer is a key part of giving a good answer.