# An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed

Tags: angular

I tried to compile my project and I'm getting an error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
See "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-sKaJxi\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I used ng add @angular/material , npm rxweb and  npm instal  and I got this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 9 - NGCC fails with an unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222467/angular-9-ngcc-fails-with-an-unhandled-exception)

Comment: What's in the error logs??

Comment: This helped for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009725/9643227 I would say, duplicated question.

Answer (score -1):

Run visual studio code as administrator i had same problem and running as administrator helped me