# ANGULAR build --prod error deploying in Google App Engine using CloudBuild

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Helle there,

To contextualize, I am working on an web application using Google App Engine (GAE). In fact, I use three different GAE services. For the backend, analysis and the frontend with Angular.

In GIT my architecture is the following:

[image: Screen capture showing the GIT folder architecture]

Indeed, I wrote a global `cloudbuild.yaml` file on root as the following to call all of others specific `cloudbuild.yaml` files in each services directories ("/api", "/analyse", "/frontend"):

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    for d in */; do
      config="${d}cloudbuild.yaml"
      if [[ ! -f "${config}" ]]; then
        continue
      fi

      echo "Building $d ... "
      (
        gcloud builds submit $d --config=${config}
      ) &
    done
    wait
```

During the deployment, an error occurs in the "frontend" service steps let see his `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

```yaml
steps:

  # Install Angular
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['install','-g','@angular/cli' ]

  # Install node packages
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: [ 'install' ]

  # Build productive files
  - name: 'node:12'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: [ 'run', 'build', '--prod', '--aot' ]

  # Deploy to google cloud app egnine
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy', 'client.yaml']
```

The error occurs for the third step (in log step 2 because of starting at 0):

[image: Screen capture showing error logs]

I am really confused with this error because I do not understand why the build method not working well. In fact, when I am running `npm run build --prod` locally there is no problem.

I hope you could help me to solve this problem.

Thanks to spend time on my issue. I love you community ❤️

**[EDIT]**

A little update to add the `package.json` dependencies.

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "The frontend part for the 4th year project",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

**I suspect that the problem comes from the `<base href="">` or from paths in the `client.yaml` inside the frontend folder**

The `client.yaml` file:

```yaml
service: default
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: frontend/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: dist
```

And the `.gcloudignore`

```
e2e/
node_modules/
src/
coverage
^(.*/)?\..*$
^(.*/)?.*\.json$
^(.*/)?.*\.md$
^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
^LICENSE
```

Comment: Try not to post images and instead post the actual code or content of your .yaml files for easier reproduction of the issue. Have you tried exploring any of the options mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222467/angular-9-ngcc-fails-with-an-unhandled-exception) as additional steps to solve the issue.

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce the issue unsuccessfully so it could be the case that a dependency is not being installed as the step runs and therefore the `ENOENT: no such file or directory` pops up.

Comment: @DanielOcando No, I do not try those options because I do not have this issue in local build using ```npm run build --prod``` It is only deploying with cloudbuild. Sorry for images, I will upload my post thanks.

Comment: @DanielOcando I am really confused because during deployment, before ```npm run build --prod``` I ran ```npm install -g @angular/cli```, so my new environment is containing the latest version of @angular/cli for now. Then, I install all necessary dependency using ```npm install```. So, I do not understand why dependencies were not installed. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Could you post the dependencies being used in order to attempt a better reproduction?

Comment: Yes I could but I think I only created a new Angular empty project from scratch with the latest version of the @Angular/cli (actually the 11.0.1 version). @Daniel Ocando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

In fact, this error occurs because the "./src" folder does not exist after deploying. My mistake, in my `.cloudignore` file I include the `src` folder so it is impossible for my application to build the `src` folder because it never imported.

The error sended was not really clear but I can go ahead now.

Thanks @DanielOcando for your time.

Comment: Oh! Good catch! I'm very glad that you solved the issue. I guess that's why I wasn't really able to reproduce your issue :)

Comment: Yes I think too. Thank you again :)