# Angular - 10 - NGCC fails with an unhandled exception

Tags: angular

when run the angular application I meet this message (after ng serve ) , I'm trying delete the node_module file then run - npm install
and , I have tried this command  :

```sh
rm -rf node_modules 
npm install
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeTyX.png)

Comment: welcome, faten banighanim! I see the error message suggest the file with the error details. may you add it's content to the question as well?

Comment: [angular-9-ngcc-fails-with-an-unhandled-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222467/angular-9-ngcc-fails-with-an-unhandled-exception)